# JS вывести число разделенное запятой

Tags: javascript

Вывожу числа с помощью setInterval. Каждый раз увеличивая число на 100. Сейчас всё выводится слитно, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после тысячи, ставилась запятая? Например:

Вместо 1567 - 1,567
Вместо 10740 - 10,740
Вместо 186491 - 186,491

```
let startN = 0;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    startN += 100;
    console.log(startN);

  }, 100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать `Intl.NumberFormat` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat - конструктор объектов, включающих языко-зависимое форматирование чисел.

```js
let startN = 0;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    startN += 100;
    //console.log(startN);
    console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(startN));
  }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так:

```js
let startN = 0;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
startN += 100;
console.log(toCommaString(startN));

  }, 100);

function toCommaString(num){
  let arr = [];

  while(num>1000){
   let n = num%1000;
   let s = '';
   if(n < 100) s = '0';
   if(n < 10) s = '00';
   arr.unshift(s + n);
   num = Math.floor(num/1000);
  }
  
  arr.unshift(num.toString());  
  return str = arr.join();
}
```